# Many to Many relationship in Access Web App

Tags: sharepoint, ms-access-web-app

I need to do a many to many relationship in my first Access 2013 web app.

I have a Parents table and a Students table. Each student can have two parents and each parent can have more than one student in the school.

Thinking like a seasoned Access desktop developer I took the usual route of creating a parents_students table to link the other two then hit a wall. How do I make the view show the relationship?

I found this topic: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/ccda03e3-a57b-4128-be72-f469c8ec30af/access-2013-web-app-handling-many-to-many-relationships?forum=accessdev

When I tried it, it is not doing what I want, or I am doing something wrong.

Seems like a very fundamental thing to be able to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got an answer over at the MSDN forums. [Link Here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/1bd3f0bb-dade-4cb4-aa00-3ccec35a9fa2/many-to-many-relationship-in-access-web-app?forum=accessdev#1bd3f0bb-dade-4cb4-aa00-3ccec35a9fa2)

Create a Parents_Students table with three fields

```
ID: AutoNumber
Student: Lookup the name field in the student table
Parent: lookup the name field in the parent table
```

To the Students View, add a SubView and add a tab called Parents. In the Data parameters set the Data Source to the Parents_Students table and the related field to Student.

Repeat the same procedure on the Parents View but use parent as the Related Field.